# Bluetooth keyboard (Keychron K12) connected but not typing after hibernate/few sleeps

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard, bluetooth, thinkpad

I recently got a Keychron K12. It's pretty nice. What's not nice though is that my laptop (ThinkPad X230 with stock BT daughterboard) doesn't like it after a certain amount of time. Symptoms appeared soon after getting it, so the culprit might have been there from the get go

symptoms:

- None of the keys are registered by the laptop (modifiers, alphanumerical, Windows)
- Local macros (e.g. backlight off) still work
- Can type on phone with keyboard after stops working with laptop
- Goes away after a restart (once it did with a hibernate iirc)
- Problem specific to my w10 install (works with mint install and another laptop with w11)

Things i've tried:

- Restart - problem comes back
- Upgrade keyboard firmware - nothing different
- Use cable - similar (takes longer to stop working)
- Disconnect and reconnect - problem persists
- Unpair and re-pair - still doesn't type
- Delete in device manager - didn't fix it
- Device manager HID tick - was already selected, disconnects (no dice)
- Disable USB suspend - ditto
- Edit: unpairing, uninstalling bluetooth, restarting, installing bluetooth, restarting, pairing - see above